# JDK 17 not deleting in macOS Monterey

Tags: java, terminal, uninstallation, java-17, macos-monterey

I just **installed JDK 17.0.6** from https://adoptium.net/ to do a course on **TMCBeans. I realized I need JDK 11** for TMCBeans to work so **I've been trying to uninstall the JDK**. I've **tried the following commands, which seem to have removed all the files.**

sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<version>.jdk

sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java

**My issue is** that when I run **java -version** and **/usr/libexec/java_home** in terminal I get the **below results**. When I go to the path, all files after /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines have been deleted. I tried restarting my laptop which did not work. **How can I fix this issue it seems like the system thinks the files are still there?**

openjdk version "17" 2021-09-14

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17+35-2724)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-2724, mixed mode, sharing)

---

/Users/mohammadtazy/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17-1/Contents/Home

I also tried using this installer to remove it https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp but this gives me the following results.
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP6nJ.png)

Comment: It sounds like your JAVA_HOME env variable is still pointing to v17.  You can change this temporarily by executing `export JAVA_HOME=\`/usr/libexec/java_home -v11\``.  Add this command to your shell's startup scripts to make it permanent.

Comment: Hey @lane.maxwell that fixed the "java -version" issue, but when I run **"/usr/libexec/java_home"** I still get this...
/Users/mohammadtazy/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17-1/Contents/Home

Comment: I also ran **/usr/libexec/java_home -V** and got the following results. It seems like none of them are being properly deleted.
 [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5dVr.png)

Comment: Can't you see that you didn't remove it? You have two installations of JDK17. Delete the appropriate paths that are given by the command...

Comment: @TheRealSlimTazy when you run that command without options it simply prints the currently set Java alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Java installation are not always in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`.
See that you have two installations in under your private directory.
Look what `java_home` gave you, and delete the given paths.

Comment: I delete the exact path that java_home gave me for both of them, but when I run it again it still shows up. I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrong. I also manually go to that path through Finder, but It's deleted there.** Basically it seems deleted through finder but Terminal still recognizes it.**@Jean-Baptiste